# Error while using str_count() function in R: 'Input must be a vector, not an environment.'

Tags: r, stringr, rlang

I have a dataframe `df`, which has a chr column `Col1`, that looks like this:

| Col1 |
| --- |
| "apple;orange;pear" |
| "orange;apple" |

I want to create **a new column**, in which I count the number of words in `Col1`. I did this previously with this code:

```
df$Count <- sapply(df$Col1, function(x) {
sum(str_count(x, ";")+1)
})
```

It worked well until now.
I've recently updated the `rlang` package to version 1.0.6 and after updating I'm constantly getting this error:

> Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
> ! Input must be a vector, not an environment.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I ran `rlang::last_error()` :

> Backtrace:
>
> 1. base::sapply(...)
> 2. vctrs:::stop_scalar_type(`<fn>`(`<env>`), "")
> 3. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(msg, "vctrs_error_scalar_type", actual = x)
>    Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

I also did a simple test vector with `c()` and tried using `str_count()` with this, but it gives the same error.

Comment: You don't need to loop. `str_count` is vectorized so you can do `str_count(df$Col1, ';')` however I do not get an error when running your code. Also, `sum()` is redundant there.

Comment: I would recommend you restart your session and try it again

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that the problem is maybe with the stringr package and I updated R to the latest version and restarted RStudio and now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R approach to count the number of words separated by a ";" is:

```
lengths(gregexpr(";", df$Col1)) + 1
# [1] 3 2
```

To create a new column, simply:

```
df$NewCol <- lengths(gregexpr(";", df$Col1)) + 1

#                Col1 NewCol
# 1 apple;orange;pear      3
# 2      orange;apple      2
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c("apple;orange;pear","orange;apple"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I noticed that R was not updated to the latest version, that's why functions from the stringr package like str_count() didn't work. I also tried your solution and it worked for me, thank you for your help!